# Making `wget` not save the page

Tags: wget

I'm using the `wget` program, but I want it not to save the html file I'm downloading. I want it to be discarded after it is received. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm new to Linux - Would the `/dev/null` thing work?

Comment: So what's the point to download it then?

Comment: @Anonymous I assume to stress the remote server.. If you don't care about the content..   I'd probably use apachebench (ab) though.

Comment: The point is likely to trigger a webhook (commonly used in IoT / smart home).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can redirect the output of wget to /dev/null (or NUL on Windows):

```
wget http://www.example.com -O /dev/null
```

The file won't be written to disk, but it will be downloaded.

Comment: This doesn't save the page, but it send email to me. Also is it possible to disable emailing ?

Answer (score 37):

If you don't want to save the file, and you have accepted the solution of downloading the page  in `/dev/null`, **I suppose you are using wget not to get and parse the page contents**.

If your real need is to trigger some remote action, check that the page exists and so on I think it would be better to avoid downloading the html body page at all.

**Play with *`wget`* options in order to retrieve only what you really need, i.e. http headers, request status, etc.**

- assuming you need to check the page is ok (ie, the status returned is 200) you can do the following:

  ```
  wget --no-cache --spider http://your.server.tld/your/page.html
  ```
- if you want to parse server returned headers do the following:

  ```
  wget --no-cache -S http://your.server.tld/your/page.html
  ```

See the [***wget man page***](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for further options to play with.
See [**`lynx`**](http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.5/lynx2-8-5/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html) too, as an alternative to wget.

Comment: I'm confused. `--no-cache` in the man page says it causes wget to "send the remote server an appropriate directive (‘Pragma: no-cache’) to get the file from the remote service"

Comment: It says to the server your client don't want a cached version of the file .. we want to get the very last release of the resource we are requesting for

Answer (score 26):

In case you also want to print in the console the result you can do:

```
wget -qO- http://www.example.com
```

Comment: I like this option best. It let's me see what it gets but doesn't save it. The switches are specifically `q` quiet mode, (it doesn't output progress and other info), and `O-` (write the retrieved document to console).

Answer (score 19):

`$ wget http://www.somewebsite.com -O foo.html --delete-after`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `--delete-after` option is the choice when you have to download recursively but you want to discard the actual content.

Comment: +1 for me, the command is intuitive -- at a glance, I can more quickly comprehend what's going to happen than `-O /dev/null`

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative is to use a tool like `curl`, which by default outputs the remote content to `stdout` instead of saving it to a file.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the "-spider" option.  I use it to make sure my web sites are up and send me an email if they're not.  This is a typical entry from my crontab:

```
46 */2 * * * if ! wget -q --spider http://www.rochesterflyingclub.com/ >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "Rochester Flying Club site is down" ; fi
```

Answer (score 3):

### If you need to crawl a website using wget and want to minimize disk churn...

For a *NIX box and using `wget`, I suggest skipping writing to a file .  I noticed on my Ubuntu 10.04 box that `wget -O /dev/null` caused wget to abort downloads after the first download.
I also noticed that `wget -O real-file` causes wget to forget the actual links on the page.  It insists on an `index.html` to be present on each page.  Such pages may not always be present and wget will not remember links it has seen previously.

#### For crawling without writing to disk, the best I came up with is the following

```
 mkdir /dev/shm/1   
 cd /dev/shm/1
 wget --recursive --relative --no-parent ...
```

Notice there is no `-O file` option.  wget will write to the $PWD directory.  In this case that is a RAM-only [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) file system.  Writing here should bypass disk churn (depending upon swap space) AND keep track of all links.  This should crawl the entire website successfully.

Afterward, of course,

```
 rm --recursive --force /dev/shm/1/*
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the --delete-after option, which deletes the file after it is downloaded.

Edit: Oops, I just noticed that has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

According to the help doc(wget -h), you can use --spider option to skip download(version 1.14).

```
Download:
  -S,  --server-response         print server response.
       --spider                  don't download anything.
```

Comment: How does this add to the other answer that mentions --spider ?

Comment: It explains what `--spider` means. Thanks.